# Google Geolocation on iOS

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, wifi, indoor-positioning-system

I'm trying to find a cross-platform indoor wifi positioning solution.  We have investigated Apple's CoreLocation.  Apple has surveyed our site and we have a working prototype that works fairly well.  However, Apple's solution is Apple only and not cross platform.  Since roughly 50% of our users use Android phones, we need a solution that is cross platform.

Using Apple's indoor CoreLocation for Apple devices and Google's Geolocation for Android devices is not really feasible since we have over 2000 sites.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/

Google's Geolocation service WOULD be cross-platform if we had a way on iOS to get the access point MAC Address and signal strength.  Unfortunately I see no AppStore approved method of doing this.  Have I missed something in the Apple Apis?

I'm also open to alternative solutions.  iBeacons would be cost prohibitive -- at least for version 1.  Location sensing LED lights are out too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out IndoorAtlas (http://www.indooratlas.com) as their magnetic field based solution has SDKs for both iOS and Android and it is software only.